# I am getting this error message in the terminal and cannot run / execute shell script on my PC. Why?

Tags: scripts

I was trying to execute the android.sh file in the terminal from my desktop; I got the following errors in my terminal:

```
$ sudo chmod +x ~/Desktop/android-sdk-linux/tools/android.sh

[sudo] password for soorej: 

$ sh ~/Desktop/android-sdk-linux/tools/android.sh

/home/soorej/Desktop/android-sdk-linux/tools/android.sh: 1: /home/soorej/Desktop/android-sdk-linux/tools/android.sh: java: not found
/home/soorej/Desktop/android-sdk-linux/tools/android.sh: 1: /home/soorej/Desktop/android-sdk-linux/tools/android.sh: java: not found
/home/soorej/Desktop/android-sdk-linux/tools/android.sh: 110: exec: java: not found
```

Comment: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14089/please-can-people-format-code-properly

Comment: If you read the error, it tells you. Java not found. Are you sure you have it installed and configured properly? [Install Java on Ubuntu with Apt-get](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-on-ubuntu-with-apt-get)

Answer (score 0):

`java: not found` is pretty self-explanatory. Please install Java and try again...

For more information on how to do that check refer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-jdk-6-7-8-or-jre)